# (Polars) How to get element from a column with list by index specified in another column

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, where first column contains lists, and second column integer indexes. How to get elements from first column by index specified in second column? Or even better, put that element in 3rd column. So for example, how from this

```
a = pl.DataFrame([{'lst': [1, 2, 3], 'ind': 1}, {'lst': [4, 5, 6], 'ind': 2}])
┌───────────┬─────┐
│ lst       ┆ ind │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [4, 5, 6] ┆ 2   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

you can get this

```
b = pl.DataFrame([{'lst': [1, 2, 3], 'ind': 1, 'list[ind]': 2}, {'lst': [4, 5, 6], 'ind': 2, 'list[ind]': 6}])
┌───────────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ lst       ┆ ind ┆ list[ind] │
│ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═══════════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 1   ┆ 2         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [4, 5, 6] ┆ 2   ┆ 6         │
└───────────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit**

As of python polars 0.14.24 this can be done more easily by

```py
df.with_column(pl.col("lst").arr.get(pl.col("ind")).alias("list[ind]"))
```

**Original answer**

You can use `with_row_count()` to add a row count column for grouping, then `explode()` the list so each list element is on each row. Then call `take()` over the row count column using `over()` to select the element from the subgroup.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"lst": [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], "ind": [1, 2]})

df = (
    df.with_row_count()
    .with_column(
        pl.col("lst").explode().take(pl.col("ind")).over(pl.col("row_nr")).alias("list[ind]")
    )
    .drop("row_nr")
)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ lst       ┆ ind ┆ list[ind] │
│ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═══════════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 1   ┆ 2         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [4, 5, 6] ┆ 2   ┆ 6         │
└───────────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: This is ingenious. Thanks. I'll test its performance and report back.

Comment: Pandas solution (df['lst'].str[0]) does not make much sense but it is still much better than such a complicated solution :/

Comment: this was changed in polars - .arr was renamed to .list  --> https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/list.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach:

Create a custom function to get the values as per the required index.

```
def get_elem(d):
    sel_idx = d[0]
    return d[1][sel_idx]
```

here is a test data.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'lista':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],'idx':[1,2]})
```

Now lets create a struct on these two columns(it will create a dict) and apply an above function

```
df.with_columns([
    pl.struct(['idx','lista']).apply(lambda x: get_elem(list(x.values()))).alias('req_elem')])
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ lista     ┆ idx ┆ req_elem │
│ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ i64      │
╞═══════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 1   ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [4, 5, 6] ┆ 2   ┆ 6        │
└───────────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks. Let's wait if it's possible using native polars api for performance reasons. My actual dataframe is pretty big so performance matters.

Answer (score 0):

If your number of unique `idx` elements isn't absolutely massive, you can build a `when`/`then` expression to select based on the value of `idx` using [`list.get(idx)`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.list.ExprListNameSpace.get.html):

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame([{"lst": [1, 2, 3], "ind": 1}, {"lst": [4, 5, 6], "ind": 2}])

# create when/then expression for each unique index
idxs = df["ind"].unique()
ind, lst = pl.col("ind"), pl.col("lst") # makes expression generator look cleaner

expr = pl.when(ind == idxs[0]).then(lst.arr.get(idxs[0]))
for idx in idxs[1:]:
    expr = expr.when(ind == idx).then(lst.arr.get(idx))
expr = expr.otherwise(None)

df.select(expr)
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────┐
│ lst │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6   │
└─────┘
```